# Insert blank space between letters of word

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I'm trying to create a function able to return various versions of the same string but with blank spaces between the letters.

something like:

```
input <- "word"
```

returning:

```
w ord
wo rd
wor d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We first break the string into every character using `strsplit`. We then  `append` an empty space at every position using `sapply`.

```
input <- "word"
input_break <- strsplit(input, "")[[1]]

c(input, sapply(seq(1,nchar(input)-1), function(x)
                      paste0(append(input_break, " ", x), collapse = "")))

#[1] "word"  "w ord" "wo rd" "wor d"
```

`?append` gives us  `append(x, values, after = length(x))`
where `x` is the vector, `value` is the value to be inserted (here `" "` ) and `after` is after which place you want to insert the `values`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `sub`

```
sapply(seq_len(nchar(input)-1), function(i) sub(paste0('^(.{', i, '})'), '\\1 ', input))
#[1] "w ord" "wo rd" "wor d"
```

---

Or with `substring`

```
paste(substring(input, 1, 1:3), substring(input, 2:4, 4))
#[1] "w ord" "wo rd" "wor d"
```